# is it possible to store few ArrayCollections inside a ArrayCollection or Array?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Actually my intension is to store dynamically generated ArrayCollections inside a ArrayCollection or Array or using any other method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Answer. Not much difficult same object storing method used.

This is my example arrayCollection

```
private var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Label:"Taxes", Value:1001},
            {Label:"Rent", Value:1005},
            {Label:"Bills", Value:1008},
            {Label:"Car", Value:1009},
            {Label:"Gas", Value:1020},
            {Label:"Food", Value:1015},
            {Label:"Taxes1", Value:1080},
            {Label:"Rent1", Value:1200},
            {Label:"Bills1", Value:100} ,
            {Label:"Car1", Value:450},
            {Label:"Gas1", Value:100},
            {Label:"Food1", Value:1750},
            {Label:"Taxes2", Value:1275},
            {Label:"Rent2", Value:1650},
            {Label:"Bills2", Value:1220},
            {Label:"Car2", Value:1550},
            {Label:"Gas2", Value:900},
            {Label:"Food2", Value:850},
            {Label:"g", Value:900},
            {Label:"h", Value:850} 
        ]);
```

this is how i store inside expenese ArrayCollection inside another ArrayCollection

```
var arr:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();

                var obj:Object=new Object();

                obj.value=expenses;

                arr.addItem(obj);
```